# Manual Draft Save - Save a draft on demand

Tags: script

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

This small script adds a save button to the editor bar that allows you to instantly save the contents of the editor as a draft. Although this happens automatically every minute or so, now you can force it to save the contents whenever you want.

...and now you can also *clear* the saved draft with the touch of a button too!

#### License

[MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

#### Download

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/draft.user.js

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Manual Draft Save
// @author        Nathan Osman
// @namespace     http://quickmediasolutions.com
// @description   Adds a button for manually saving a draft
// @include       http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://superuser.com/*
// @include       http://serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://stackapps.com/*
// @include       http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

// Here I borrow a (slightly modified) function I wrote for another
// UserScript that makes it easy to provide functions
// with complete access to the page.
function EmbedFunctionOnPage(function_contents)
{
    var exec_script = document.createElement('script');
    exec_script.type = 'text/javascript';
    exec_script.textContent = "(" + function_contents.toString() + ")()";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(exec_script);
}

// Now here is the function that we embed on the page.
EmbedFunctionOnPage(function() {

    $('.fl').first().append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="heartbeat.ping();">Save</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(\'#wmd-input\').val(\' \'); $(\'#wmd-preview\').html(\'\'); heartbeat.ping();" style="margin-right: 35px;">Clear</a>');

});
```

#### Platform

Since this little 'app' is a UserScript, it can be installed as-is in Chrome. Firefox users can use GreaseMonkey and Opera users can follow [these instructions](http://my.opera.com/operafan2006/blog/2007/02/13/how-to-install-user-java-script-in-opera).

### Contact

I can be reached at... `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`

### Code

Nothing but JavaScript and jQuery!

Comment: Regarding your installation instructions:  note that the [script tag wiki](http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) has installation instructions for the various browsers.

Comment: @Rebecca: Ya... but a lot of people come here from external links (especially on Meta) so they don't see those. Still, I can remove it if you'd like.

Comment: @JeffM: I fixed it, but I had to move it to the bottom of the editor. Thanks!

Comment: Just have a refinement suggestion.  The links shouldn't be shown when editing an existing post, it's just unnecessary (and potentially harmful).  Detection shouldn't be too difficult.  The URL is in the form, `{site}/posts/{postid}/edit`.  Otherwise this is basically what SO should have had in the first place.  Even works for new questions too.  :)

Comment: @JeffM: Yeah... since it's a UserScript, I can limit the domain to certain URLs.

Comment: Link broken, can't use.

Comment: @Asad: it's back now.

Comment: Chrome on Android?

Answer (score 6):

This is great.  How about a feature request?  Should be doable I think.

A matching clear button.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if I should be posting this as a comment or an "answer".  Looking at other app pages, people seemed to put these here.

Comment: I like it... but I don't think the StackExchange engine supports this. (Like the site itself doesn't even have a means of doing this.)

Comment: I noticed that if you clear the text and then save, it does actually save now (but with no message).  Unlike in the past where it didn't save at all.  Otherwise you could replace the text with a single space and it will save that.  You should be able to alter the contents of a text box right?

Comment: @JeffM: Sure... I didn't realize that blank submissions were accepted. I was getting 500's before.

Comment: @JeffM: Ya... still getting 500 errors when a blank entry is submitted... would a space (`' '`) be okay?

Comment: @George: I'd be okay with that.  I'm sure [other](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/68957/manually-resetingdiscarding-saved-question-drafts) [people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/68140/add-a-clear-button-when-a-saved-draft-is-loaded) will appreciate that not having to see their old post.

Comment: @JeffM: ...and **done!** I just re-uploaded the new script.

Comment: @George: Now, even more awesome.  Time to update the screenshot and description again.  :)

Comment: @Jeff M: A request won't do the trick. [I've done a request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/68957/137977) few months ago, but was declined.

Comment: @Robert: I know, I even supported it (I've been linking to it and other related requests everywhere).  But _this_ request was to add to the button to _this_ app, not SO.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Or, you could just do this...

```
-function EmbedFunctionOnPage(function_contents)
-{
-    var exec_script = document.createElement('script');
-    exec_script.type = 'text/javascript';
-    exec_script.textContent = "(" + function_contents.toString() + ")()";
-    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(exec_script);
-}
-// Now here is the function that we embed on the page.
-EmbedFunctionOnPage(function() {
-    $('.fl').first().append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="heartbeat.ping();">Save</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(\'#wmd-input\').val(\' \'); $(\'#wmd-preview\').html(\'\'); heartbeat.ping();" style="margin-right: 35px;">Clear</a>');
-});
+document.querySelector("fl").firstChild.innerHTML += '<a href="#" onclick="heartbeat.ping();return false">Save</a> | <a href="#" onclick="$(\'#wmd-input\').val(\' \');$(\'#wmd-preview\').html(\'\');heartbeat.ping();return false" style="margin-right:35px;">Clear</a>';
```

Comment: I like using dom. It does escape your HTML.