# OBSOLETE - Add Draft Save Links

Tags: script, obsolete, editing, posts

> ### Obsolete:  Install and source links are dead.  Script was written for much older version of the sites.

### Screenshot

[image: for drafts]
[image: for edits]

### About

This is a simple Greasemonkey script which adds Save and Clear buttons for use when composing question/answer drafts.  Otherwise when editing a post, it checks for updates from concurrent edits.  As an added bonus, the Save hotkey (Ctrl+S) returns along with a Clear hotkey (Ctrl+Backspace) and a "Return to Question" link has been added when editing questions, useful if you want to open the question in a separate tab after having started editing.

This is an alternative implementation of the script [found here](https://stackapps.com/questions/2086) from which the code was inspired by.  It unfortunately didn't handle certain use cases well, this aimed to improve on it.

There are primarily 2 aspects of the original script that I wanted to improve on:

1. Control when the links would be included and what type of link it was.
   *You can save drafts of new questions or answers but not when edits are made as far as I can tell.  So the appropriate link names are used for each view.*
2. It was impossible to clear the contents until you pressed a keyboard key within the editor.
   *This will simulate a key press prior to attempting to save or clear so the changes go through.*

#### Download

- [Userscripts Page](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/102056)
- [Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/102056.user.js)
- [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/102056)

#### Platform

Written for and tested on Firefox 4.0 on Windows 7.  I will be trying to maintain compatibility with Chrome in future releases.  Specifically on Chrome 11.0 on Windows XP.  Hopefully combinations of either browser and OS will still work.

### Contact

Please use this page as means of contact.  This is part of a personal learning exercise using Javascript so support will be limited as I have no practical experience with it.  Feedback and improvement suggestions would be appreciated.

### Future

This will be part of a larger project which is a collection of scripts to enhance Stack Exchange if and when I figure out how to do it.

Comment: I'm the author of the original script and I would love to hear what improvements you've made :)

Comment: @George: I have included the "improvements made" in the description.

Comment: Updated: Added hotkeys!

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't work on Chrome (don't think it works on any browser). The beat function is no longer in `heartbeat` but hidden in `StackExchange.cardiologist`

Comment: Yeah it's been broken since they've revamped the question pages. I haven't had the chance to update it. Thanks for pointing out the change, hopefully the fix will just be a matter of changing those variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use this answer to keep track of progress such as bugs and plans.  That way it will be able to keep everyone up to date on the progress.

#### Acknowledged Bugs

- <s>Does not work on other browsers like Chrome</s> *(fixed)*
- <s>Ctrl+S keyboard shortcut not working on Chrome.</s> *(fixed)*

#### Future Plans

- <s>Add keyboard shortcuts for these links</s> *(implemented)*
- <s>Add delays between consecutive save/clear attempts</s> *(implemented)*
- <s>Remove links when saving is not possible</s> *(implemented)*